# Google App boto file stored in inappropriate directory

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I installed Google Cloud SDK and it dumped a `.boto` file directory in to the My Documents folder (e.g. C:\Users\John) which is a wildly inappropriate location. I do see many instances of the boto file in the Python files, a couple of dozens of instances / examples:

```
return os.path.join(self.LegacyCredentialsDir(account), '.boto')
os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.boto')),
```

Where do I go to change the path to something appropriate? An appropriate path would be something such as `C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\.boto` in example.

At the top of the file:

> This file contains credentials and other configuration information needed
> by the boto library, used by gsutil. You can edit this file (e.g., to add
> credentials) but be careful not to mis-edit any of the variable names (like
> "gs_access_key_id") or remove important markers (like the "[Credentials]" and
> "[Boto]" section delimiters).
>
> [Credentials]
>
> Google OAuth2 credentials are managed by the Cloud SDK and
> do not need to be present in this file.
> To add HMAC google credentials for "gs://" URIs, edit and uncomment the
> following two lines:

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions of Boto don't seem to be a great fit for App Engine.  I ran into this issue about a year ago, and I don't remember all of the details, but I avoided Boto3 and stuck with Boto 2.47 and that worked well for me.

For my use case, I only needed help with SES. If you need many other AWS services then YMMV.

Comment: I only code my own stuff all from scratch so I when people talk about piles of dependencies deeper than layers of rock in the Grand Canyon I get lost. I installed Google Cloud SDK yesterday, am I somehow able to remove or downgrade Boto?

Comment: I really doubt that installing Google Cloud SDK (built by Google) caused Boto (3rd party library for AWS) to be installed.  You need to figure out what caused Boto to be installed, but you don't need it for any Google Cloud products.

Comment: I use Advanced Find & Replace (http://www.abacre.com/afr/) and it has all those references mentioned in the OP. Google names itself numerous times. Additionally there was nothing else installed on my computer yesterday.